# UIFoundation 2 slices for architecture arm64 error Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I am getting following error

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Avijit/Dogra/App/EZMCOM_LATEST 5.31.56
>   PM/EZMCOM_LATEST/Connect/Library/iphoneos' ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Connect/Library/libPods.a, file was built for archive which is not the
>   architecture being linked (arm64): Connect/Library/libPods.a ld: in
>   '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation',
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
>   (2 slices) for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

How to fix this error?

Comment: @rmaddy. How to fix this please help me.

Comment: Fixed by removing the syetem framework from directory ex.Avifoundation,Xc.test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing the system library `UIKit.framework` (for others it might be different) from `build phases` which was imported automatically.

Because the one I imported is an old one and i used `otool` to check it's linked library, it has `UIFoundation.framework` inside.

I didn't check what's the difference between the old UIKit and the new one but I found this corrected the problem.

I hope this will help anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: Ok. Thats Great Roger.